# global variable for recursive functions in python

Tags: python, recursion, global-variables, global

I am using pyhton to for a recursive function named **sphereinput** the function needs to return a variable name **result** as output.By declaring it as global in recursive function I wil not have to use return at the end of function.
Will the function return **result** having the correct answer when called in main file of my program.
My reservation is that for each call to the function **sphereinput** in itself the global variable result will be updated accordingly ,right?

```
def sphereinput(parameters)
    global result
    Recursive call to sphereinput
    result=assigned value
```

Note that I did not use return statement here.Do I have to? 
Also when i define it in same file as main code after every call to function it starts executing the code lines below function again which are part of main code and must not be executed.

If i have to define this function in another file how do i call it from main file and then which variables will have to be defined global both in main and function code file?

Comment: Save yourself from the scourge of global variables, and just return it. It's easier, and it's less likely to go wrong.

Comment: Agree with @zondo.  Also, the fact that you can't immediately reason about what the code is doing is not a good thing.  Recursive functions should generally be side effect free, that is they don't effect anything outside of their local scope.

Comment: If i just return the variable ,will it give correct answer even though recursion is involved?

Answer (score 0):

The result will be updated accordingly, but not returned unless you explicitly do so.

I do not know what you mean with

> Also when i define it in same file as main code after every call to
>   function it starts executing the code lines below function again which
>   are part of main code and must not be executed.

To call it from main file you have to first import the module (=file) and then call its function:

```
import myfile
myfile.sphereinput(args)
```

You do not have to define the result variable anywhere else as long as you make sure that you don't use it before you call sphereinput.

You can call your function recursively in another way as well, which does not require a global variable:

```
while True:
  temp = sphereinput(args)
  if temp is None:
    break
  result = temp
```

Here you simply return None when you do not want any further recursions.

Comment: Thanks for the help .Will elaborate more on the problem if this doesnt work out!